# Issue forwarding an URL to a cached file with mod_rewrite & minor confusion about page caching with Sinatra

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching, sinatra

We are running a Sinatra app that caches some static pages to a `cache` folder and we would like to serve these files with Apache rather than Rack.

This is our proposed user flow (for example):

1. User visits http://domain.com/dir1/dir2 (eg: http://domain.com/archive/books)
2. Sinatra's router checks if an up to date cached version exists, if not, render out the file and save to `public/cache/archive/books.html`
3. Redirect the user to the appropriate location so Apache can serve the static file from `http://domain.com/cache/archive/books.html` but display the URL as `http://domain.com/archive/books`

We are trying to use a simple mod_rewrite rule to achieve this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cache/$1.html
```

But can never seem to get it to work (throws a 500 server error).

I suppose an initial and perhaps more important question would be: **Is this the right way to go about this?** We are using [Sinatra Cache](https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-cache), and I assume it generates the files but doesn't handle the routing to serve a cached file if it exists? (The gem is generating the static pages for us, but our server is always serving a dynamically generated file, not a cached static one)

This gem also hasn't been updated in nearly 5 years so we're unsure if this is even a recommended path to go down in any case (It seems to generate the static files we need quite well)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
# First make sure .html file exists in cache before rewriting
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ cache/$1.html [L]
```